# Custom taxonomy query "IN" or "NOT IN"

Tags: mysql, wordpress, metadata

I am trying to work on this query

```
$query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'location',
                     'operator' => 'IN',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $availableRegions,
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'location',
                     'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $notavailableRegions,
                )
            ));
```

And the sql query for this tax query is:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) JOIN wp_icl_translations t
ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id 
AND t.element_type IN ('bla') JOIN wp_icl_languages l
ON t.language_code=l.code
AND l.active=1
WHERE 1=1  


AND (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (200) 

OR wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( 
SELECT object_id 
FROM wp_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (201,203,205,206) )
)
```

but this is not what I need really

**I want the query to be like this:**

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) JOIN wp_icl_translations t
ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id 
AND t.element_type IN ('bla') JOIN wp_icl_languages l
ON t.language_code=l.code
AND l.active=1
WHERE 1=1  


AND (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (200) 


/* What I need to be is this line */
OR wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (201,203,205,206)

)
```

or if I can select ("NOT_EXIST" or "IN") will be good for me also, any suggestions to save my weekend guys.

Comment: Please check the array parameter sequence affect on you wp_query(). Like I have checked the order of parameter is like 'taxonomy', 'field', 'terms' and then operator.